# Rsync doesn't handle time correctly on a mounted folder on MacOS

Tags: rsync, backup, macos, nas

I have a mounted a folder from my NAS with `mount -t smbfs -o -d=755,-f=755 //nas.local/backup ~/backup`.

I now try to rsync a local folder to this distant folder with something like `rsync --modify-window=30 -irvt --info=progress2 --delete-after test-dir ~/backup`.

I've tried a lot of rsync options, but I'm always getting `>f..t.......` on all the files, so I always have `speedup is 1.00` even if I run the same rsync multiple times in the row, without changing anything in the source folder. I don't have this issue when running the rsync between 2 local folders.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the filesystem on the NAS something that warrants the use of `--modify-window`, e.g. FAT?

Comment: I use `BTRFS` on my NAS. I tried the `--modify-window` to see if it could help with my problem, but it didn't :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NAS allows ssh login you will generally get a significantly more efficient file transfer if you ignore the SMB share and have `rsync` talk to the NAS directly:

```
rsync -rtiv --info=progress2 --delete test-dir remoteUser@nas:~/backup
```

Otherwise, remove the `--modify-window=30` and try the copy again:

```
rsync -rtiv --info=progress2 --delete test-dir ~/backup
```

For either suggestion you should to ensure the local and remote systems use the same time source so that they have the same date/time. NTP can be a good choice for Internet-connected systems.

If you are writing to a FAT filesystem you will need to provide `--modify-window=1` to overcome the limitation of having only 2-second granularity in the filesystem metadata. (I know of no system where timestamps are accurate only to the nearest minute; MacOS APFS itself is accurate to the nanosecond. It doesn't mean there aren't any, but requiring `--modify-window=30` seems exceedingly unlikely unless you're trying to work around a completely different issue.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Already tried without the modify-window parameter, didn't help. I however tried rsync directly through ssh and it indeed worked, thanks ! No sure it really solves the issue raised here, but it suits me as I can now do my backup ! Thanks !

Comment: @RobinFrcd happy to try and help resolve your Samba/time issue. But to do that I would need to see a few examples of problematic files (start with `ls -l` for source and corresponding destination). Put this into your question, formatted with the `{}` button